# Island Sanctuary and additional card draws

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have [Island Sanctuary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4136) in play and someone casts [Braingeyser](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=1192) on me, forcing me to draw X cards.

Island Sanctuary's Oracle text says "*If you would draw a card during your draw step, instead you may skip that draw*". Since Braingeyser's card draws would presumably be outside of the draw step Island Sanctuary's ability would presumably not kick in. BUT... the Oracle rulings kinda contradicts this understanding, saying "*If you get multiple draws or you use a spell or ability during the draw step to draw extra cards, you can have the replacement effect apply to any one or all of those*". Like the implication of that is that it can be applied to additional card draws.

So how would Island Sanctuary work with a card like Braingeyser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial understanding is correct; the Gatherer ruling is dealing with the case where you get multiple draws *during your draw step*, for example if you cast [Brainstorm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brainstorm) during your draw step.